# Finding architecture of a system in node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I have tried using the built in OS module from node.js to find the OS architecture of the system but it appears to respond with the incorrect value for os.arch(), it is returning ia32 even though the system is actually 'AMD64' in the command line:

```
C:\>SET Processor
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
```

I assume this is because there is only a 32 bit version of node-webkit so it is returning the architecture of the node-webkit instance rather than the OS. What would I need to do to find the OS architecture?

Comment: On Windows try `process.env.PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` (which correctly returns AMD64 on my system) although I don't know where that particular property gets set.

Comment: Yep worked, thanks. That value is set in the system env when you install windows so it should always be set